# 80/90s show for kids FPP set in space live action

Tags: story-identification

80/90s kids show set in the future, first person perspective so you feel like you’re part of the action. My brother and I have been looking for this show for over 10 years. I think it was American or Canadian? It was on a VHS but maybe it could have been a fake ride? I remember it definitely being on tape.

There’s a machine or a shuttle that launches you into space to a station where you get trained for something. There are people in robots walking in the background and the robots look a little like *Star Wars* robots but also the ones from *Hypernauts*.

---

I went through the [FMV](http://fmvworld.com/games.html) and what I’m looking for is something like a training movie with robots that look like the *MechWarrior* or *MechCommander* games. Maybe they had an FMV on VHS(?)